# R, knitr, xtable, alternating row colors

Tags: r, colors, knitr, xtable

I'm trying to produce a table with `xtable` in R using `knitr` with alternating row colors. I can print a table in the PDF output but can't quite figure out the `add.to.row` command in the `xtable` manual along with the `colortbl` package.

Comment: It's often helpful to provide a minimum working example of what you're trying to do, along with your efforts and where you fail.

Comment: If you do not insist on coloring but highlighting with (strong) emphasis would fit your needs, then you might give a try to `emphasize.*` functions even with HTML/docx/odt formats in `pander` package: http://blog.rapporter.net/2013/04/hihglight-cells-in-markdown-tables.html

Comment: The package gridExtra [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414001/gridextra-colour-different-rows-with-tablegrob][1] offers also nice table formatting.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414001/gridextra-colour-different-rows-with-tablegrob

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This figure was produced using the code at the bottom. I hope you don't break your eyes detecting the light grey color (I almost have, on one of my screens).

```
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
rws <- seq(1, (nrow(mydf)-1), by = 2)
col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rws))
print(xtable(mydf), booktabs = TRUE,
      add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws), command = col))
```

The key is to define row indices (`rws`) and their respective colors (`col`). If you want colors to differ between rows, you'll need to play around with `paste`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}

\begin{document}

<<do_table, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
rws <- seq(1, (nrow(mydf)), by = 2)
col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rws))
print(xtable(mydf), booktabs = TRUE, 
   add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws), command = col))
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: you interpretation of _gray code_ highlighting: shades that differ by one hex digit?

Comment: @baptiste I'm afraid I don't understand the question. My choice of color has no particular motivation. I just picked something more or less at random as it's only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the code! I know it is some years ago, but do you know how to make the colors start with the first row? Just starting the sequence by 0 gives me a black square.

Comment: @panuffel copy my code, open a new question, show what you've tried and see solutions rain down on you. :)