# Pass two set of rules for rows to xtable

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

Please consider the following MWE (variation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580525/1707938))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}

\begin{document}

<<do_table, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
rws <- c(1,3,5,6,7)
col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rws))
print(xtable(mydf), booktabs = TRUE, 
   add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws), command = col))
@

\end{document}
```

With this I have set a rule for the rows 1,3,5,6,7. Now let's say I would like also to set a different colour `[green]` for different rows (2,4). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to construct a `col` vector that contains all corresponding colors for each position in the table. Your example with two differently colored rows:

```
<<do_table, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
rws <- c(1,4)
col <- c("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", "\\rowcolor[gray]{0.7}")
print(xtable(mydf), booktabs = TRUE, 
   add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws), command = col))
@
```