# Boldify the contents of bottom row in xtable

Tags: r, latex, xtable

How can I bold the contents of the last row of xtable?. The bottom row contains sums and I would like it boldified.

I use the following:

```
<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=

test.xt <- xtable(test, label="table", caption='test')
align(test.xt) <- "|l|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|"
print(test.xt, tabular.environment='tabularx', include.rownames = FALSE,  width="\\textwidth", floating=FALSE)
@
```

Comment: I think you need to manually paste bold tags around each entry in the row, unfortunately.

Comment: Can't it be done using `add.to.row`? I use it to add color background. See this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867670/pass-two-set-of-rules-for-rows-to-xtable/20869673#20869673

Comment: It looks like you actually want to use the `sanitize.text.function` as per this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762431/adding-rows-or-boldify-single-row-names-with-print-xtables-add-something-in-be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working example (in Rmarkdown, but should be easily adaptable.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tabularx}
  - \usepackage{array}
---

```{r, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE}
library(xtable)
test <- rbind(mtcars[1:10, 1:5], 
              colSums(mtcars[1:10, 1:5]))
rownames(test)[11] <- "Sum"

test[11, ] <- paste0("BOLD", test[11, ])

bold.somerows <- 
        function(x) gsub('BOLD(.*)',paste('\\\\textbf{\\1','}'),x)


test.xt <- xtable(test, label="table", caption='test')
align(test.xt) <- "|l|l|l|r|r|r|"
print(test.xt, tabular.environment='tabularx', include.rownames = FALSE,  width="\\textwidth", floating=FALSE, sanitize.text.function = bold.somerows)
```
````

And if you can manage without borders for now, you can use `pixiedust` (table borders in LaTeX documents are the next thing on the to do list for `pixiedust` and should be done in a few weeks).

````
```{r}
library(pixiedust)
test <- rbind(mtcars[1:10, 1:5], 
              colSums(mtcars[1:10, 1:5]))
rownames(test)[11] <- "Sum"

dust(test, keep_rownames = TRUE) %>%
  sprinkle(rows = 11, bold = TRUE) %>%
  sprinkle_print_method("latex")
```
````

Comment: Thanks, sanitize.text.function is the way to go.